# Moving WP site to another domain

Tags: wordpress

I have simple `4.2 WP` site with theme `Twenty Twelve` and `Polylang` plugin `ver. 1.7.6`. in domain `mysite.co.nf`. Now I deciced to move it to another domain `mysite.newdmn.eu`. I have copyed all files from old domain to new one using FTP. Then have exported `DB` to `SQL` script. Have edited SQL script by replacing strings `mysite.co.nf` with `mysite.newdmn.eu` using Notepad++. Then I have imported this SQL to my new site DB, edited `wp-config` to connect to new DB and from first point of view site is running except several things:

1. No header picture. (Actually this is not problem, but strange..)
2. No multi language icons and it is not possible to switch between languages.
3. Can't open one page - new server shows that it not exists. This is simple text page that looks the same like other ones. Link of this page looks the same structure like other pages.

How to solve these problems? 
And what is best practices while moving WP sites?

Comment: Go to Settings->Permalinks and save changes (you don't need to change anything). That should solve #3

Comment: No, this doesn't helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit SQL by using editor is always a bad way to update the domain url. Because themes and plugins may serialize php objects into string format and store it in DB. If you replace domain url by using editor, it may break your site.

WordPress codex mentioned : https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Changing_Your_Domain_Name_and_URLs

> If you do a search and replace on your entire database to change the
>   URLs, you can cause issues with data serialization, due to the fact
>   that some themes and widgets store values with the length of your URL
>   marked. When this changes, things break.

The suggested way is to use search and replace tool like https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/, or some backup plugin like Duplicator or Backup Buddy.

Also suggested this well written article about WordPress migration.
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/04/moving-wordpress-website/

For me, I always do it by myself without using any plugins. My steps is as follows:
**1.move all files under wp-content**
**2.import db**
**3.do search and replace by using https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/**

Answer (score 0):

Few times I had to update not only domain but also file path on server.

But the best you can do is using Backup Buddy (paid) or Duplicator (free) plugin (or any other that fits you, but those two are the best imo, and I do at least few migrations a month).

Comment: I tried to use Duplicator, but got error "Error 500: Script Execution Failure". Anyway, wp-snapshots folder with archive exist on server. Can I somehow use it?